# Virus scan xcode or eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, xcode, malware, virus

Is is possible for an Xcode or Eclipse project to contain malicious code that would render the computer the project is being opened up on susceptible to a virus?  Or assuming the answer is definitely; are there ways to protect against this?

Specifically, if I downloaded a project from a repository from an unknown source, could it open up security issues on my machine?  Is there virus software which can scan for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any project that you download and run on your machine executes just as any other normal process, thus it can do whatever any other desktop application can do, including malicious actions like installing a virus or sending spam from your machine.

There are virus scanners which can scan any file on access, i.e. whenever a file is read from your harddisk, it is scanned directly before. Such a scanner can prevent known malware from executing through this way. I do not have a recommendation for a specific scanner, but google will help you to find the right one for your needs.